# when program can execute without main in java 6 using static block then why there is need of main method

Tags: java

for example-

```
   class A3{  
  static{  
  System.out.println("static block is invoked");  
  System.exit(0);  
  }  
}
```

Someone explain me the reason.

Comment: What are you trying do?

Answer (score 2):

A "program" cannot execute without `main()` (unless it is a servlet or an applet, in which case the web container or the web browser manages the corresponding [entry point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point)). In your example, a static block, it will only be executed once some other *running* class initializes (usually by referencing) the class `A3`.

[JLS-8.7. Static Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) reads (in part)

> A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is initialized ([§12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)).

Comment: this is according to java 7?? because in java 7 it will not be executed but it will get executed in java 6.

Comment: @Prashant By what? If there is no `main()` then there is nothing being executed...

Answer (score 2):

*Static blocks* are executed when a Class is first *initialized* (after it is *loaded*). A `main()` method serves as an entry point for the application. Classes are (implicitly) loaded (and probably *initialized*) when they are first referenced.

See the difference?. You need to specify an entry point to a program / application by *putting main() method* in a class.  A static initializer is run when a class is initialized, it is not the entry point of the program but a set of statements which are run (usually to do some setup work like initializing static fields (like maps)) when the class is being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The static block isn't necessarily invoked at program startup; it can be delayed to whenever the class is first initialized. It is necessary to specify a main class with a main function to indicate the entry point that should be invoked at program startup and because that's how Java works.

Comment: *whenever the class is first loaded* - I think it should be *initialized*. instead of *loaded* :)

Comment: Thanks @TheLostMind. For someone not regularly writing classloaders or dynamically loading classes that is a bit of a technicality, but that is a good point.

Comment: I learnt that detail *the hard way* :)..

Comment: I can certainly believe that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print simple print statements static block is enough. but the real time program never contains system.out.println statements. and more over you can't access non static variables, methods..etc so it mean it is useless.